# AWS Lambda trying to write event.body to Aurora DB throws error

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-aurora

I have a table in Aurora DB. I am trying AWS API Gateway, AWS Lambda and AWS Aurora DB.

I created a Lambda function which does receive request from API Gateway and triggers the handler function but it does not write the event.body to the table.

```
exports.insertBill = function(event, context, callback) {


     context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

     console.log(event.body);

     var query = rDBConnection.query('INSERT INTO Bill SET ?', event.body, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
           callback(null, {"statusCode": 400, "body": JSON.stringify(err)});

        } else {
        var recordId = result.insertId;
         console.log("Record ID " + recordId);
         var result = {recordId};
         callback(null, {"statusCode": 200, "body": JSON.stringify(result)});
       }
      });



  }
```

the code does connect to DB. When I try setting the body as follows (from Lambda Test Interface)

```
  "body": "{\n     \"vendor_Id\" : 101,\n  \"user_Id\"  :  2224\n  \n }",
```

it does display the body as (from console.log) :

```
{
     "vendor_Id" : 101,
  "user_Id"  :  2224

 }
```

but throws an SQL error :

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "body": "{\"code\":\"ER_PARSE_ERROR\",\"errno\":1064,\"sqlState\":\"42000\",\"index\":0}"
}
```

when I try hard coded value like `{ "vendor_Id" : 101, "user_Id"  :  2224 }` in rDBConnection.query instead of event.body --> in that case the code writes a DB record .

I am not sure what I am missing here. I receive similar results while testing from API Gateway Test Interface.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. The API Gateway sends to Lambda the `body` as JSON string so I did JSON.parse on the `body` before writing to the db.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format